# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Lifehacks breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11          8
Users destroyed                                  12          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                  11          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue             8        346
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0         16
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          5        281
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        298
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                26        673
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               21        245
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                                4          0
Questions protected                               0         28
Questions migrated                                6          0
Questions flagged⁴                                4        202
Questions closed                                121         43
Question flags handled⁴                         101        105
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                   5          8
Posts locked                                      0         50
Posts deleted⁵                                  247        210
Posts bumped                                      0         51
Comments flagged                                 20        124
Comments deleted⁶                                92        165
Comment flags handled                            75         69
Answers flagged                                  22        641
Answer flags handled                            450        213
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...